# How can I programmatically create a shape in Android

Tags: android-layout, android

I have following myRec.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="1dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
            <stroke 
                android:color="@color/my_button_border"
                android:width="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
     </item>
</selector>
```

.... and would like to create the same shape programmatically so that I can freely change color in runtime.  How can I achieve it?   Much thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the  [android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html)  class and the [Shape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html) class subclasses, suchs as:

- PathShape
- RectShape
- ArcShape
- OvalShape
- RoundRectShape

ShapeDrawable receives a shape in the constructor, and then you have a lot of function to modify the shape. Also, you can retrieve the Paint asociated to the ShapeDrawable so you can alter things like the color and so.

Also, **take a look at this small example:**

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/shape-drawing-example-in-android/

where you can see some diferent shapes, and some efects suchs as the CornerPathEffect,

Comment: It looks promising but a lot of code for just simple color change. Suppose I want to use this xml and load it in runtime but just want to change the color in runtime yet, the range of rgb color is fairly large and cannot define anywhere in the xml file. Any idea?  Thanks much Carlos

Comment: i dont know if i get what exactly you need, but about color, you can read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html (search for `<solid>` and `<gradient>`) and also go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: also, it is ok if you put as much as you can in the xml, since is easier to maintain, and also is more MVC

Answer (score 0):

Use shapedrawable, gradientdrawable with

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/CornerPathEffect.html